# How to find an item that matches a field using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have an array of object like below,

```
const items = [
    {
        id: '1',
        category: 'one',
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        category: 'two',
    }
]
```

from the above items array of objects i want to get the id of that object whose category is equal to 'two'

so the output should be 2.

so i have tried something like below,

```
const id = items.map(item => {
    return item.find(i => i.category === '2');
}
```

but this throws an error cannot read item of undefined.

could someone help me fix this. i am new to programming. thanks.

Comment: Because you need to use the item instead of i variable to access the category, so you have to leave the find method without passing a param and use item.category instead of i.category

Answer (score 1):

```
const id = items.map(item => {
    return item.find(i => i.category === '2');
}
```

**find** can be used on arrays not on objects. In the above code item is an object.

```
const item = items.find((item) => item.id === '2')
```

This would give you the whole object with id = 2.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the correct solution

```js
const objectWithCategoryEqualsTwo = items.find(item => item.category === 'two')
const id = objectWithCategoryEqualsTwo.id
```

Find returns an item in an array that matches your predicate, to get the id you then have to do `.id` on the returned object.

Your code snippet below doesn't work because:

1. you're checking `i.category` to be equal '2', where the data says its 'two' instead, so the item is not found and undefined is returned.
2. You're using `.map` on the array which returns a new array where each item in the array is equal to the returned value by the function passed to map, yet you expect the result to be the id.
3. You're using `.find` on each item in the array which is of object type whereas `.find` is an array method.

If you're still not familiar with javascript array functions like `map`, `filter`, `find`, `reduce`, `some`, `every`, etc..

You can also do with a normal for loop or `forEach`

```js
items.forEach(item => {
  if (item.category === 'two') {
    return item.id
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the reduce method as well

```
const id = items.reduce((acc, item,index) => {
    if(item.category === 'two') {
        return item.id;
    }
  })
```

Comment: thats not how reduce should be used, probably won't work
would work with a normal for loop however

Comment: @KhaledOsman refer to the js fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/f96os32e/